# How to Connect Hyperledger Fabric External Channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am going to build a channel and peers with hyperledger fabirc.

So I'm going to connect to a channel built with hyperledger fabric using two computers, how do I connect?

first, hyperledger fabric on one computer. Then I installed the fabric on another computer. What should I do here?

Comment: and anothor Questions about hyperledger fabric channel

Does the hyperledger fabric have the channels first, then peers are joined the channel..

 If the computer that created the channel dies, does that channel die? So what's the difference the central network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Hyperledger Fabric network is initially defined, there is a default channel that includes all of the organizations in the 'consortium'. These are the initial, founding, members of the network. Additional organizations may be added.

If you study the 'first-network' [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html), you can see the genesis block being generated by the `configtxgen` command from a YAML definition of the network to be deployed `configtx.yaml`. The first component brought up is the ordering service, followed by the peer nodes that are optionally connected to other peers via the `gossip` protocol. There are two aspects to gossip: gossip within an org's peers, and gossip between orgs. The former is configured with properties in the `core.yaml` or corresponding ENV variables, the latter is configured with the AnchorPeers property in the configtx.yaml for the channel.

When you create a new channel, you specify the address and port of the ordering service that will manage that channel, and you specify the orgs that will participate in that channel. Then, you join peers to the channel and optionally install chaincode (for endorsing peers).

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain in more detail? For example, when I want to join a channel, do other computers need to know the IP and port of the computer that has the channel to join? If so, where is the documentation for entering the IP and port?

Comment: Not with the upcoming 1.2 release which adds a discovery service to the peer. The discovery service will basically provide you with a map of the blockchain network. With previous versions, you don't need to reconfigure the other peers, but you do need to know about the new peer's IP etc to incorporate it into any endorsement.